# OPENGL C# Solid Cylinder

Tags: c#, opengl

why my cylinder not giving solid form?? it looks like transparent on other side , i want it be solid and the colour only on outside
 here is my source code

```
    public override void glDraw()
    {
        GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL.glLoadIdentity();

        GL.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -50);

        GL.glRotatef(this.xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  //rotate searah x
        GL.glRotatef(this.yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  //rotate searah y
        GL.glRotatef(this.zrot, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  //rotate searah z




        GL.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);  //mulai gambar gl polygon
        for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 359); iogl++)
        {
            //Tabung
            GL.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
            GL.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 25);
            GL.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 25);
            GL.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
            GL.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 6);
            GL.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 6);


        }
        GL.glEnd();




        this.xrot += this.xspeed; //tambah kcepatan searah x
        this.yrot += this.yspeed; //tambah kcepatan searah y
    }       
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Request a depth buffer when you create your GL context.
2. Enable depth testing (`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`).

Comment: i should use polygon or quads?

Comment: @UnidentifiedZ: Quads.  Well, triangles ideally, but quads are OK.